# If this matrix is singular, then its rank is greater than two.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading [Hoffman and Kunze's linear algebra book](http://uap.unnes.ac.id/ebook/mathematics%20ebook/Algebra/Linear%20Algebra,%202nd%20ed%20-%20Kenneth%20Hoffman,%20Ray%20Kunze,%201971.pdf) and on page 188 they said:

[image]

I don't know why $rank(A-I)\ge 2$ because of $A-I$ is singular. I don't understand neither why they conclude $rank (A-I)=2$, using the fact $rank(A-I)\ge 2$.

Answer (score 2):

$A-I$ singular implies that it has rank at most $2$. But the first two rows are linearly independent, so the rank is at least $2$. Combining these inequalities shows that the rank is exactly $2$.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that $rank(A-I)\ge2$ is nothing to do with it being singular.  It is that you can very easily see that $A-I$ has (at least) $2$ linearly independent columns, for example the first two.

Next, as $A-I$ is $3\times3$ with rank $\ge2$, the rank must be $2$ or $3$.  But if the rank were $3$ then it would be invertible, which it isn't (because "singular" means "not invertible").  So the rank is $2$.

Answer (score 2):

The reason they say that rank $A-I$ is obviously $\geq 2$ is because the first two columns are linearly independent, so they are not using the fact that $A-I$ is singular. Now, $A-I$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix so the rank has to be either $0,1,2$ or $3$. Saying $A-I$ is singular means that there is a non zero kernel or equivalently (by the [rank nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)) that $A$ does not have rank 3. So we conclude that $2 \leq \mathrm{rank} (A-I) < 3$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'because of'. The matrix $A - I$ is singular since $1$ is a zero of the characteristic polynomial.

In addition to that, the rank is not equal to $0$, since there are nonzero columns and the rank is also not equal to $1$, since not all of the three rows are linear combinations of just one row (i.e. all of them would be multiples of the same single row).